# Python :: Ternary Operator :: Not able to use multiple statements

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements, ternary-operator

I have the scenario something like this.

```
a = 3
b = 5
c = 7
# using ternary operator now,
print a; c = 1 if a < b else print b ; c = 2
```

Which raises this error when I use assignment operator on both the sides

```
SyntaxError: can't assign to conditional expression
```

If I use it on one side like this, it works fine.

```
a = 1 ; c = 1 if a < b else b
```

So question is How to use multiple statements in Python Ternary Operator?

Comment: What is the purpose of using the conditional expression? If you would write the code using a normal `if` *statement*, how would it then look?

Comment: it is the `a = 2` part that should not be in the expression... `c = 1 if a < b else 2` would work. but may not be what you want.

Comment: Also know that the conditional expression is an ***expression***. You can not have multiple *statements* in any of the branches, only a *single expression*. If you want to do multiple statements, you need an `if` *statement*.

Comment: Your edit makes it even worse. In Python 2 (which you seem to be using) `print` is a *statement* and the conditional expression is used to select one of two *expressions*. A statement in Python doesn't have a result so the `else` part makes no sense.

Answer (score 4):

### Short answer: you cannot have statements in ternary expressions.

A ternary expression is not meant to contain statements, only expressions. In Python2, `print` is a statement and it is thus a invalid syntax to have it inside a ternary.

```
c = 1 if a < b else print b
#                   ^^^^^^^ In Python2 `print` is a statement
```

The purpose of a ternary is to conditionall *return a value*. So both branches should be expressions that preferably return a value of the same type.

```
# This is a good use of ternary expressions
c = 1 if a < b else 2
```

Any other case should probably be using an *if-statement*.

```
if a < b:
    c = 1
else:
    print b
    c = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not perform multi statement with Ternary expressions. But you can do this. I am not sure whether it will run faster or not.

```
a = 3
b = 5
c = 7

def onTrue():
    print(a)
    c = 1

def onFalse():
    print(b)
    c = 2

onTrue() if a < b else onFalse
```